# JNI access violation when calling non static java method from C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to call a non static java method from c++.

Sample2.java:

```
public class Sample2 {
    public int intMethod(int n) {
        return n*n;
    }
}
```

JNITest.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory.h>
#include <jni_md.h>
#include <jni.h>
using namespace std;

#ifdef _WIN32
#define PATH_SEPARATOR ';'
#else
#define PATH_SEPARATOR ':'
#endif

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    JavaVMOption options[3];
    static JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    long status;
    jclass cls, stringClass;
    jmethodID mid;
    jstring jstr;
    jobjectArray args;

    jint square;

    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=D:\\Studie\\EXP\\Code\\Workspace\\JNItest\\bin"; //2APL\\build"; //Workspace\\JNItest\\bin";
    options[1].optionString = "-verbose";
    options[2].optionString = "-verbose:jni";
    memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

    if (status != JNI_ERR)
    {
        cls = env->FindClass("Sample2");
        if(cls !=0) {
            mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "intMethod",  "(I)I");
            if(mid !=0) {
                square = env->CallIntMethod(cls, mid, 5); //this is where it all crashes
                printf("Result of intMethod: %d\n", square);
            }
        }
        jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

the program actually finds the method and gets to the `square = env->CallIntMethod(cls, mid, 5);` part where the access violation occurs.
If I change it all to a static method it runs fine, but I need to be able to call non static methods as well...

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You are calling a non-static method but you don't have an object to call it on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you've called `FindClass`, you need to create an instance of that class by calling `NewObject`. To do so, you first need to get the constructor ...

```
jmethodID constructor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "<init>", "void(V)");
```

then create an object

```
jobject object = (*env)->NewObject(env, cls, constructor);
```

then you can call the instance function

```
square = env->CallIntMethod(cls, mid, object, 5);
```

Comment: Still what I eventually try to achieve is calling the following function: `public static void main(String[] args) {new Sample2();}`
Is there a way to get to that object created in java from within c++?

Comment: @Spekkie Use `javap -s Sample2` to see the signatures of constructors and methods. That helps when writing calls to GetMethodID and the like.